# My dogs won't stand up in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, wii-u

In Minecraft for Wii U, my dogs had been working fine for ages. However, one time one of my dogs was in a boat that I destroyed, and following this the dog wouldn't stand up. Then, none of my other dogs would stand up either.
Does anyone know how to fix this?